# multiprocessing - closing file opened in run()

Tags: python

I have subclassed `Process()` to do some logging to file (used multiprocessing as the volume of data to be processed was causing slow downs in the main program; and threading didn't help).

A simplified example is below:

```py
import multiprocessing

class LogListenerProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, file_pth):

        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.file_path = file_pth

    def run(self):
        some_file = open(self.file_path, "w+")
        print(some_file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = LogListenerProcess("some_file.txt")
    x.start()
```

This works fine and when I stop the process, I *believe* it closes the file. However, is there a way for me to deliberately close the file when I call `terminate()` or do I have to open/close the file outside the `process.run()` and pass it in as an arg rather than the file path? (ETA: I didn't like the idea of opening a file in one process and then using it in another process, which is why I pass the file path)

Or have I subclassed `Process()` incorrectly?

Comment: The way you stop the process is, I think, important here. What signal do you send the process ? (how do you stop it ?)

Comment: I check if it is `alive()` and, if so, send `terminate()` and wait for `join()` and finally `close()`

Comment: For now I have used a multiprocessing.Event() to send a signal to the process to tidy up before closing. But not sure if that's the correct way or if there is a 'built in' way.